# Upper bound for arithmetic rank of ideals in a local domain

Tags: commutative-algebra

Does anyone knows how to prove or disprove that if $(R,m)$ is a Noetherian local domain of dimension $d$ one has that $\mu(I)\leq d$ for every ideal $I\subset m$?
Where the arithmetic rank of $I$ is $\mu(I)$ and $\subset$ means strictly contained.

Comment: hi yo yo; just to clarify, by arithmetic rank, do you mean that $\mu(I)$ is the minimal possible size of a generating set for $\sqrt{I}$?

Comment: Yes, exactly that

Comment: Really? I thought arithmetical rank is the minimal number of elements in $I$, generating an ideal $J$ with  $\sqrt{J}=\sqrt{I}$. If so, the standard proof is the following (sketch). Inductively, choose $a_1,\ldots, a_r\in I$ such that any prime ideal containing $a_i, 1\leq i\leq r$ and not containing $I$ has height at least $r$.

Comment: I don't understand, can you please are more details?

Comment: I think the two definitions are equivalent and the reason is that $\sqrt{(a_1,...,a_t)}=\sqrt{(a_1^s,...,a_t^s)}$ the proof is what follows: one inclusion is clear. For the other take $g^n=\sum g_ia_i$ and than take $g^{nsr+1}$. The polynomial $g^{nsr}$ is in $(a_1^s,...,a_t^s)$ becouse an homogeneous polynomial of degree $sr+1$ in $a_1,...,a_t$ must contain at least one $a_i^s$. With this fact it is clear that $min\{a_1,..,a_t\in R|\sqrt{(a_1,...,a_t)}=\sqrt{I}\}=min\{ a_1,..,a_t\in I|\sqrt{(a_1,...,a_t)}=\sqrt{I}\}$